# Using PDI transformation in Pentaho BI server as data source for report parameters

Tags: reporting, pentaho, kettle

Any advice on how to use PDI transformation as data source for report parameters in BI server's console?

I've uploaded the prpt reports to BI server but the I get a message "Error parsing parameter information". The `.prpt` and `.ktr` files are both in the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, just realized that the issue could be solved by adding Transformation (KTR) as a resource. In this case, one can use the `File-Resources` menu selection. In the dialog select the transformation you wish to import and pick text/xml format. Give the resource a name and save it. You must save your PRPT file again (`File-Save`).

The caveat here is that transformation should be in the same folder as PRPT file. Then in the data sources, don't select transformation via folder path, but use the name of the resource that was assigned during the previous step (there is no drop down menu for looking thorough the files). You have to know exact name of the resource in order to do so.

Comment: yup, just remember with this approach every time you update the KTR you have to "refresh" the resource as it is actually embedded in the PRPT.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs carefully. I suspect it's not finding the KTR. When you select the KTR in the prpt it usually (annoyingly) saves the whole path, so it's probably the full path to the ktr as defined on your dev box.

This does work, so do persevere!

Comment: That is very close, but first, you have to load this transformation as a resource. See my answer above :)